# Make header with icons aligned on the right HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, position

I have a header on my website that needs to have some icons on the right side. I have no idea what to do because the icons are positioned correctly but the div doesnt expand to them, which should be the default behaviour.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days HD</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <div id = "socialMediaHeader">

        <div id = "socialMediaIcons">
            <a href = "http://twitter.com/kh_days_hd"><img class = "socialMediaIcon" src = "twitter_icon.png"></a>

            <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4mVq6c8YpYOuiTwuzejgDw"><img class = "socialMediaIcon" src = "youtube_icon.png"></a>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

#socialMediaHeader {
    background-color: black;
}

.socialMediaIcon {
    margin: 10px;
}

#socialMediaIcons {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}

#socialMediaIcons::after {
    content : "";
    display : block;
    clear : both;
}
```

EDIT: this code is a work in progress of me trying to fix the problem, disregard any stupid errors

Comment: Put it on fiddle man. So we can see where you're going wrong. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioned elements are removed out of the flow. Their height, padding or margin will not affect their parent in any way.

To make your parent element **`#socialMediaHeader`** visible you would need to define a height on it.

```
#socialMediaHeader {
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Also, note the `position:relative`.
Absolute positioning always looks for the nearest positioned ancestor. This makes sure your icons are always inside `#socialMediaHeader`.

Comment: But i want the header to be a percentage height of the page, and when I try I have the same issue as before

Comment: Percentage heights only work if you specify the height on a parent. In your case, if you add, `html, body {height: 100%}`. You should be able to set a percentage on the header.

Comment: Here is an example, of how you can use percentage heights on your header. https://jsfiddle.net/L1m292jz/1/

Comment: Ok. i got the percentage height to work for #socialMediaHeader, but how do i make the icons fill to fit the div but stay proportional?

Comment: Depends on the percentage heights that you decide to go with. You can explicitly set a height on the icons and make them responsive using [media queries -- W3C Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

Comment: I want the image to scale with the header, it shouldnt be that complicated

Comment: It is complicated! Specially for a person who doesn't know basic things! Start to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Give your socialmediaheader a width of 100%, height of X and position relative

```
#socialMediaHeader {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%; //optional but if you change the right: of you icon your header would still fill the whole page width
    height: 50px; // or any other height
    position: relative;
}
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6h21kncg/4/

Sorry it's a bit ugly and took me till breakfast was over to read you question correctly - forgive me, but I'm on my Phone right now...

Answer (score 0):

You are using position: absolute and this takes out the socialMediaIcons div out of socialMediaHeader so this div doesn't have anything in it. You need to give it a height.